# Can you change Gutenberg Block Type with ACF Pro's acf_register_block function?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I've been searching for a little while on a way to change one block type to another by using ACF's acf_register_block function and am hitting a wall.

I'm wondering if this is possible, as per the ACF documentation, "Any argument from the JavaScript registerBlockType() function may also be used." (Source: ACF's docs, [acf_register_block_type](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_register_block_type/) under "$settings").

It's my understanding I should be able to tap into Wordpress' native "transforms" option to be able to convert my block type to another, similar, block type. Source: [WP Block API - Block Registration](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-registration/#transforms-optional)

I'm looking to convert two block types with identical fields - FAQs with Styling to/from FAQs without Styling. Below is my code, contained in my **functions.php** file.

```
// faq
    acf_register_block(
      array(
        'name'        => 'faq',
        'title'       => __('FAQ Section'),
        'description'   => __('A custom FAQ block.'),
        'render_callback' => 'my_acf_block_render_callback',
        'category'      => 'faqs',
        'icon'        => 'editor-table',
        'keywords'      => array( 'faq', 'faqs' ),
      )
    );

    // faq no style
    acf_register_block(
      array(
        'name'        => 'faq_no_style',
        'title'       => __('FAQ Section No Styles'),
        'description'   => __('A custom FAQ block.'),
        'render_callback' => 'my_acf_block_render_callback',
        'category'      => 'faqs',
        'icon'        => 'editor-table',
        'keywords'      => array( 'faq_no_style', 'faqs' ),
      )
    );
```

Does anyone have any input as to if this is possible? Is there a way to create blocks via JavaScript, using ACF's fields? I'm using the latest versions of Wordress and ACF.

I have tried the following without luck:

```
// faq
    acf_register_block(
      array(
        'name'        => 'faq',
        'title'       => __('FAQ Section'),
        'description'   => __('A custom FAQ block.'),
        'render_callback' => 'my_acf_block_render_callback',
        'category'      => 'faqs',
        'icon'        => 'editor-table',
        'keywords'      => array( 'faq', 'faqs' ),
        'transforms' => array(
          'to' => array(
            'transform' => function() {
              print_r("test");
            },
          )
        )
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked on ACF PRO 5.8.8 source code and looks like acf_register_block_type does not support `transforms`. ACF Blocks are very useful, but they are not as flexible yet, unfortunately. But maybe you can add a field where you indicate different types of your block and add different css class to the block template and style accordingly? That's how I usually do that.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about this approach and will probably have to go this route. I was hoping to not have to add additional fields, as I've got this set up on several sites now. However, thanks for the suggestion. I'll keep digging!